# Blazor Passing List<T> between components

Tags: asp.net-core, binding, components, blazor, data-sharing

I am having issue with the code, I have my page layout as below.
I am communicating to database to get data for Main Content. It is `List<SomeClass>` that I am getting from database. Now I want same `List<SomeClass>` to be available for RightContent. Both components are custom and have different layout but can share same List rather than making same call twice. (Sequence is MainContent Initialized() method gets called first)

I created a service class AppDataService with below property. Also added to `IServiceCollection services` in startup.

```
public List<SomeClass> sharedListOfSomeClass = new List<SomeClass>();
```

In MainContent I am injecting AppDataService and assigning sharedListOfSomeClass with database values.
Now if I am injecting AppDataService  in Right Content and and trying to access sharedListOfSomeClass I am getting it as null.

I know I am missing binding here because both the components are different in terms of html and can't bind it to any html tags.

Could any one please help me out to achieve this. I want to make single call to database for both the components.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

If you want to have some global state of the app and share it between different components, the most reasonable way to do it is to create a `State` class that will contain the global state data

```
public class State
{
    public List<SomeClass> SomeClassObjectsCollection { get; set; } = new List<SomeClass>();
}
```

In your `Startup` (or `Program` if you use Blazor wasm) you should add a `State` object as a singleton

```
services.AddSingleton<State>()
```

and on every page, where you need an access to state (or even in `_Imports` if you want to access it often) add

```
@inject State State
```

After that on any page you can refer to `State.SomeClassObjectsCollection` and get the same data.

The key point is adding a state as a singleton. If you will add is as transient or even scoped, the dependency container will create new instances of `State`.

Comment: The problem with this though is if the app is used by multiple users when it goes into production each app will have access to that ONE singleton. For example, if it is a shopping cart. Every user in the app will see each other's shopping cart.

Comment: Not really. The blazor server creates a channel — a state for each user's session. And blazor wasm is at all executed in the user's browser. So each time the SPA will be loaded and initialized for a user a new singleton will be createted, which will exist as long as user keeps the browser tab open or reloads a page.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to pass the list to the components as parameter. Define a parameter in the component's code.

```
[Parameter] public List<SomeClass> sharedListOfSomeClass { get; set; }
```

In the parent pass the set the parameter:

```
<MyCustomComponent sharedListOfSomeClass="@MyVariableHoldingTheListValues" />
```

Other way I can think of is to make a static list and reference the static list in the components.

The scenario of the injection gives you null because the service could be registered as transient or scoped servervice. Not as singleton.